# reset bootstrap input spinner clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to reset the bootstrap input spinner clicking a button. I tried using document.getelementbyId().value = "0" but with no success. I also tried using reset() but it didn't work. Any ideas on how to reset it?

```
function resetScoreSing() {
    document.getElementById("scoreSing1").reset();
    document.getElementById("scoreSing2").reset();
}
<div class="container" style="width: 160px;"><input type="number" value="0" step="1" id="scoreSing2"></div>
button type="button" class="clear" id="RSSing" onclick="resetScoreSing()">Reset Score</button>
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you have currently?

Comment: ready i have already added

Answer (score 0):

It worked with:

```
$("#scoreSing1").val('0');
$("#scoreSing2").val('0');
```

Comment: You could also use `document.getElementById("scoreSing1").setValue("0")` https://github.com/shaack/bootstrap-input-spinner#programmatic-change-and-read-of-value